# Not able to change button height using css

Tags: css

Not able to increase the height of button. It shows by default 18px in computed style.
Changing the width works OK. all the other styles which i applied margin-left, top also works but why not Height??

```
   <input name="cancel" id="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel">
```

css

```
input#cancel {
   margin-top: 30px;
   margin-left: 48px;
   width: 70px;
   height: 24px!important;
}
```

I also tried to give the height in id like this

```
   #cancel {
       height:24px;
   }
```

Let me know if you need computed style which is shown in browser. please help

Comment: You might post the computed style.  I tried this here with no additional mark-up and it works:  http://jsfiddle.net/mmzrP/

Comment: try adding `display:inline-block;`

Comment: Nope. inline-block doesnt help. i changed the height to 1000px in jsfiddle - I dont see the button height getting increased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `-webkit-appearance: none;` to your class to disable safari's default button styling

```
<input name="cancel" id="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel">
input#cancel { 
    margin-top: 30px; 
    margin-left: 48px; 
    width: 70px; 
    height: 42px; 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Ltmpq/3/)**

Comment: I tried both your fiddle & changed the height to 1000px, i dont see any increase in height

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: try adding this rule to your class: -webkit-appearance: none;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mmzrP/3/

Comment: great! It worked - Accepted ur answer

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (See the Fiddle link I posted as a comment to your post).  My guess is there is a style conflicting with it and overriding it.  The height setting worked regardless of display type for me, so something else must be overriding the height.